# Парсинг файла с помощью Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream, filestream

Подскажите как такое можно сделать с помощью стримов? Я в них новичок, может хотябы с помощью каких метов можно сделать. Буду рад любой помощи!

**Вопрос!**
Есть логи старта и финиша с id(подстрока лога) участника и его временем старта(подстрока лога)
используя java 8 (Stream API только) и Parsing Logic достать информацию из файла при повторении тегов использовать первое вхождение.

```
Parsing Logic
-------------
TAG_STARTS_AT = 4;//начало подстроки для id
TAG_ENDS_AT = 16; //exclusive - конец подстроки для id
TIMESTAMP_STARTS_AT = 20; // начало подстроки времени
TIMESTAMP_ENDS_AT = 32; //exclusive - конец подстроки времени

Пример лога
-------------------------------------
aaA2058001c71dae00011608131001342900FS (id=058001c71dae, time=160813100134)
aaA205800221804b00011608131001343300FS
aaA105800221406700011608131001344100FS
aaA1058001c8375000011608131001344200FS
aaA10580022186b200011608131001345d00FS
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    final String fileName = "file.txt";

        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

            final List<Logs> logs = stream
                    .map(t -> new Logs(t.substring(4, 16), Long.valueOf(t.substring(20, 32))))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            System.out.println(logs);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

class Logs {

    private final String id;
    private final Long time;

    Logs(String id, Long time) {
        this.id = id;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Logs{" + "id=" + id + ", time=" + time + '}';
    }
}
```